# Calling a PowerShell script from Wix with Parameters

Tags: json, powershell, parameters, wix

I'm struggling with this, as the Wix CustomAction calls PowerShell.exe with one set of parameters (Including the PowerShell script), but then I need additional parameters passing to the powershell script. I've tried to simplify, tried various quote marks in various places to try and logically seperate the parameters, but I'm having no luck. Here's what I have:

```
<SetProperty Id="ReplaceConnectionString"
 Before ="ReplaceConnectionString"
 Sequence="execute"
 Value="&quot;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoProfile -File &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]ReplaceConnectionString.ps1&quot; &quot;MyParam&quot;" />


<CustomAction Id="ReplaceConnectionString" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />


<InstallExecuteSequence>        
        <Custom Action="ReplaceConnectionString" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming `MyParam` is a declared parameter in the script, you'll need to bind some value to it, eg. ```... -MyParam:&quot;SomeValue&quot;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was as Mathias suggested, which is to use the parameter names.

The other issue was that PowerShell doesn't like a trailing / on a parameter, which was fixed by adding an extra / to the param. Here is what I wound up with:

```
    <SetProperty Id="ReplaceConnectionString"
    Before ="ReplaceConnectionString"
    Sequence="execute"
    Value="&quot;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoProfile -File &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]ReplaceConnectionString.ps1&quot; -servername &quot;[DB_SERVER]&quot; -database &quot;[DB_DATABASE]&quot; -configPath &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]\&quot;" />
```